# Webpack dev server not finding index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following webpack config:

`webpack.common.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '.git'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
  },
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    compress: false,
    port: 9000,
    http2: false,
    https: false,
    liveReload: true,
    watchFiles: ['src/**/*'],
    client: {
      overlay: false,
    },
    static: {
      directory: __dirname,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
    })
  ]
});
```

My folder structure:

```
webpack.common.js
webpack.dev.js
src/
├─ index.html
├─ index.js
```

Tools versions:

```
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0"
"webpack": "^5.52.0"
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0"
"webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
```

**QUESTION:** When running `webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js` in the root folder, I'm getting 404 error for `index.html` when accessing `localhost:9000/index.html`. Shouldn't `index.html` be created in memory?

I do get this in the log when starting the server:

```
asset bundle.js 901 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 5 KiB [emitted]
```

How not to get 404 error and access `index.html` that's in memory? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with this line in `webpack.common.js`:

```
publicPath: "/dist/"
```

By removing it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this webpack config fix your problem, the index.html may be in a folder "public" and not in "src", and set enable the inject on index.html

Try this config :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports ={
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js','.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use:{
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use:{
                loader: 'html-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            use:[
                "style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                "sass-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use:{
                loader: "svg-url-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            use: [
                "file-loader",
                {
                    loader: "image-webpack-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
   },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./public/index.html",
        inject:true,
        filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer:{ 
    static: {
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    open:true,
    compress: true,
    port: 3000
    }
}
```